# Copy specific file type keeping the folder structure

Tags: cp

I have a folder structure with a bunch of *.csv files scattered across the folders. Now I want to copy all *.csv files to another destination keeping the folder structure.

It works by doing:

```
cp --parents *.csv /target
cp --parents */*.csv" /target
cp --parents */*/*.csv /target
cp --parents */*/*/*.csv /target
...
```

and so on, but I would like to do it using one command.

Answer (score 226):

`find` has a very handy `-exec` option:

```
find . -name '*.csv' -exec cp --parents \{\} /target \;
```

Comment: Probably because of this \{\} \;

Comment: `'{}'` works just as well

Comment: Reading the ``find`` manual I just found out it's recommended to use ``-execdir`` instead of ``-exec``. The manual says: ``There are unavoidable security problems surrounding use of the -exec action; you should use the -execdir option instead.``

Comment: Even though `-execdir` is safer than `-exec`, simply replacing one with the other does not preserve the folder structure as intended.

Comment: Why I get message 'Omitting directory' when I try to copy them with your command ?

Comment: Can you explain why the braces have to be escaped here?

Comment: @VickyDev your directory *hidden*, i.e., it's name began with `.`?

Comment: This is _much_ slower than the [xargs method](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/314823/117839), at least on Windows: 4 seconds vs 4 minutes.

Comment: "Why I get message 'Omitting directory' ?" It's because at each level that it's copying, there are subdirs; and `cp` is telling you that these subdirs are not being copied. You adapted the command to your needs, and whatever you have in `-name` includes subdirs, which in the "csv" example, it didn't. You would need `-r` to recursively copy the subdirs; but you *don't* want that, because copying the subdirs is being covered by the `find` itself. Depending on what you're doing, obviously. Maybe you want. But most probably not. :$

Comment: @Noumenon the [help page for find](https://ss64.com/bash/find.html) says: "-exec command ; Execute command; true if 0 status is  returned.   All  following arguments to find are taken to be arguments to the command until an argument consisting of `;` is encountered.  The  string  `{}` is  replaced by the current file name being processed everywhere it occurs in the arguments to the command, not just in arguments where it is alone, as in some versions of find.  Both of these constructions might need to be escaped (with a `'\'`) or quoted to protect them from expansion by the shell."

Comment: When using find in a terminal on a mac, the --parents option is not recognized. I'm using cpio as per the answer from @iain there.

Comment: This answer saved my day!

Comment: This answer does not save the structure.

Comment: @Miguel Maybe it's your version of "find", or "cp", or shell. This works fine in a standard linux system with bash. Let us know what are your specs and maybe someone can help... or you can post a new question, with all the details.

Comment: How can this be modified to copy a folder rather than a file.

Answer (score 96):

You could also use `rsync` for this.

```
$ rsync -a --prune-empty-dirs --include '*/' --include '*.csv' --exclude '*' source/ target/
```

If you want to keep empty directories from the source tree, skip the `--prune-empty-dirs` option:

```
$ rsync -a --include '*/' --include '*.csv' --exclude '*' source/ target/
```

If you do *not* want symlinks, modification dates, file permissions, owners etc. preserved, please replace `-a` with another combination of `-rlptgoD`.  ;-)

Comment: `-m` is a shortcut for `--prune-emty-dirs`.

Comment: Also, the `-R` option can be added to copy the parent directory structure of source. (cf. my answer here.)

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that rsync is excruciating slow at finding matching files though. It takes like 100 more time than find. Is there anything that can be done about this?

Answer (score 67):

You can use [find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) and [cpio](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cpio) in pass through mode

```
find . -name '*.csv' | cpio -pdm  /target
```

This will find all .csv files in the current directory and below and copy them to /target maintaining the directory structure rooted in `.`.

If you use

```
find /path/to/files -name '*.csv' | cpio -pdm /target
```

it will find all of the file in `/path/to/files` and below and copy them to `/target/path/to/files` and below.

Comment: I tried all the answers top down up to this one, and this was the only one that worked on the first attempt

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I found the [GNU docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/cpio/manual/html_node/Copy_002dpass-mode.html) helpful: _"In copy-pass mode, [requested by the `-p` option, cpio] reads the list of files to copy from the standard input; the directory into which it will copy them is given as a non-option argument."_ ... _"-d     Create leading directories where needed."_ ... _"-m     Retain previous file modification times when creating files."_

Comment: I want to do the same as the first line but copy all the contents of a folder and not only the csv files.

Answer (score 40):

The `cp` command permits multiple source arguments:

```
cp **/*.csv --parents ../target
```

**CAVEAT:** I'm using a recursive glob here; this is the `globstar` option in Bash 4+ and `ksh`, and is supported by default in `zsh`. Recursive globs **do not** match hidden files and folders, and the [some implementations follow symlinks while others do not](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/96653/38050).

If your shell doesn't support recursive globs, or if you'd prefer not to use them, you can do the following:

- `*.csv */*.csv */*/*.csv */*/*/*.csv` -- this is of course very redundant and requires knowing how deep your directory structure is.
- `$(find . -name '*.csv')` -- This **will** match hidden files and folders. `find` also supports specifying whether or not symlinks are followed, which may be useful.

Comment: this is exactly what i tried (the recursive glob) and it found some but not all? pretty weird. I got the same exact result when using the npm copyfiles script but if i use the find command it finds everything...

Comment: @Randyaa I'll need some more details on which files, exactly, weren't found in order to help you. You may find the discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28776648/1858225) and continued [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113668/discussion-between-kyle-strand-and-ns-du-toit) about the precise behavior of the recursive glob useful.

Comment: turns out recursive glob wasn't enabled for some reason... I've never run into this before but i corrected it with just an execution of `shopt -s globstar` immediately before my command and all is well.  Thanks for the follow up!

Comment: `--parents` was what I was looking for. thanks

Answer (score 31):

This one worked for me:

`find -name "*.csv" | xargs cp --parents -t /target`

If you have file names with spaces, add options `-print0` and `-0` like suggested in one of the comments:

`find -name "*.csv" -print0 | xargs -0 cp --parents -t /target`

Comment: Best answer with most simple syntax. Works just fine and is easy to remember. In many cases `find [things] | xargs [do stuff]` is very powerfull.

Comment: Agreed. Very straightforward compared to some of the other answers.

Comment: Breaks if you have spaces in filenames

Comment: @MichelePiccolini Spaces in filenames can be handled with `find -print0` and `xargs -0`.

Comment: @pasztorpisti, is there any downside to that? If not should the answer not simply be edited to include your suggestion.

Comment: @Kvothe Unix pathnames are zero-terminated byte arrays. All byte values are allowed (even newline) and the only special byte values are slash and zero. For this reason `-print0` with `-0` is probably the most reliable way to transfer pathnames from `find` to `xargs`. Note that without `-0` the `xargs` command interprets the input in a special way that is described in the specification of `xargs`. (It allows single and double quoted strings and escaping.) This default behavior (that is rarely what people want) can be changed not only with `-0` but also with the gnu specific `-d`.

Answer (score 12):

From `rsync`'s manpage:

> -R, --relative
>
> Use relative paths. This means that the full path names specified on
>   the command line are sent to the server rather than just the last
>   parts of the filenames.  This is particularly useful when you want to
>   send several different directories at the same time. For example, if
>   you used this command:
>
> ```
> rsync -av /foo/bar/baz.c remote:/tmp/
> ```
>
> ... this would create a file named baz.c in /tmp/ on the remote
>   machine. If instead you used
>
> ```
> rsync -avR /foo/bar/baz.c remote:/tmp/
> ```
>
> then a file named /tmp/foo/bar/baz.c would be created on the remote
>   machine, preserving its full path.  These extra path elements are
>   called "implied directories" (i.e. the "foo" and the "foo/bar"
>   directories in the above example).

So, this would work, too:

```
rsync -armR --include="*/" --include="*.csv" --exclude="*" /full/path/to/source/file(s) destination/
```

Comment: Thanks for providing this answer. Compatible with BSD userland (macOS), **and** paths with spaces in them.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you want to replicate this structure from `./source` to `./destination`:

```
cd source
find . -name "*.csv" | xargs tar cvf - | (cd ../destination ; tar xfp -)
```

I'm prepared to count that as one line, the `cd source` being a shell builtin.

Comment: `tar` has the `-C` option to avoid having to change the directory first.