# mv and cp directory hierarchy?

Tags: directory, file-copy

Can I also move or copy directory hierarchy of a file when I `mv` or `cp` the file?

For example, if I `mv` or `cp` `dir1/dir2/file` elsewhere, it will only `mv` or `cp` `file`. What if I want to also `mv` or `cp` `dir1/dir2`? Rather than `mkdir -p dir1/dir2`, can it be done with one command?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83593/copy-specific-file-type-keeping-the-folder-structure - Server Fault duplicate : http://serverfault.com/questions/180853/how-to-copy-file-preserving-directory-path-in-linux

Answer (score 10):

You can use `cp`'s `--parents` switch:

```
$ mkdir -p step1/step2/step3
$ touch step1/step2/step3/file
$ mkdir copy

$ cp --parents step1/step2/step3/file copy
$ ls copy/step1/step2/step3/file
copy/step1/step2/step3/file
```

`mv`, however, does not have a `--parents` switch, but you could do something like:

```
$ find step1/step2/step3 -name "file" -exec cp --parents {} copy/ \; -delete
```

Which will:

- Find the file.
- Copy it (along with its parents) to the destination.
- Delete the original.

You could create a function for this:

```
mvparents()
{
    [[ $# -ne 2 ]] && echo "2 arguments needed." && return
    [[ ! -r "$1" ]] && echo "$1 is not readable." && return
    [[ ! -d "$2" ]] && mkdir -p "$2"

    find $(dirname $1) -name "$(basename $1)" -exec cp --parents {} $2/ \; -delete
}

$ mvparents step1/step2/step3/file copy/
```

This might require a few adjustments if you try to move several files though. Here is an example (working in bash, but no guarantees for other shells) :

```
mvparents()
{
    [[ $# -lt 2 ]] && echo "Usage: $0 [source] <source> ... [destination]." && return

    # Get the destination directory.
    for dest; do true; done
    [[ ! -d "$dest" ]] && mkdir -p "$dest"

    # Copy the arguments and remove the destination.
    parameters=( "$@" )
    unset parameters[${#parameters[@]}-1]

    # For each source file: find, copy, delete.
    for source in "${parameters[@]}"; do
        if [ -r "$source" ]; then
            find $(dirname $source) -name "$(basename $source)" -exec cp --parents {} $dest/ \; -delete
        else
            echo "$0: $source is not readable."
        fi
    done
}
```

<sub>Well... that's a little longer than I expected but it should do the job</sub>

Edit: As [Sebastian Piech](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/84705/sebastian-piech) pointed out in a comment, relying on `cp` to do `mv`'s job is quite a performance killer, since `mv` does not originally need to *copy* the file, just edit its metadata. You might want to replace the above loop with:

```
for source in "${parameters[@]}"; do
    if [ -r "$source" ]; then
        [[ ! -d "$dest/$(dirname $source)" ]] && mkdir -p "$dest/$(dirname $source)"
        find $(dirname $source) -name "$(basename $source)" -exec mv {} "$dest/$(dirname $source)" \; -delete
    else
        echo "$0: $source is not readable."
    fi
done
```

However, since this thing relies a **lot** on the value of `$PWD`, I would ask you to be very careful should you use it.

Comment: There is no switch for `mv`, but you can find alternative solutions. I edited my answer.

Comment: It's ok if you don't need great mv 'power' feature: mv command used to move a file/dir within the same partition doesn't touch files themselves but only changes directory content description. That makes mv very fast as it doesn't copy files content.