# Simple method for copying a file and preserving it's path?

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, cp

I want to copy a file from drive A to drive B, preserving the file's path.  For instance

```
/A/x/y/z/file.txt to /B/x/y/z/file.txt
```

However, you cannot `cp` a file to a directory that doesn't already exist.  I searched and saw some results for moving whole directories using paths, but in my use case I need to be able to do this by specific individual files.

In my example above assume `/B` contains no directories currently, and so I would need to create `x/y/z` before the `cp` command would be successful.  The string that I have to work with is the full current file path, `/A/x/y/z/file.txt`

Comment: See [Copy specific file type keeping the folder structure](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/83593/22142)